# SVG filter <feOffset> - possible to set dx and dy in pixel value?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

I'm currently in the phase of learning and implementing SVG and I've stumbled upon a "drop-shadow" issue in which I can't seem to set the drop-shadow to be assigned in `px` values.

As an example:

```
<filter id="shadow" height="130%" width="130%">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="0"></feGaussianBlur>
  <feOffset dx="1" dy="1" result="offsetblur"></feOffset>
  <feFlood flood-color="#fff"></feFlood>
  <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"></feComposite>
  <feMerge>
  <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
  <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
  </feMerge>
 </filter>
```

The above gives a shadow that is bigger than what I had hoped was the css equivalent (but obviously isn't):

```
filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 #333);
```

Trying to assign a `px` value to `dx` and `dy` results in an error, and I'm hoping that someone could tell me whether it's possible to do what I'm aiming for. A full example with "svg + inline filter" and "svg + css filter" can be seen below:

```css
#css-filter{
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 #333);
filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 #333);
}
hr{
clear:both;
}
svg, p{
width:50%;
float:left;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="icons-defs" aria-hidden="true" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
<defs>
 <filter id="filter" height="130%" width="130%">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="0"></feGaussianBlur>
  <feOffset dx="1" dy="1" result="offsetblur"></feOffset>
  <feFlood flood-color="#333"></feFlood>
  <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"></feComposite>
  <feMerge>
  <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
  <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
  </feMerge>
 </filter>
 </defs>
 <svg filter="url(#filter") viewBox="0 0 16 28" height="150" width="150" fill="yellow">
<path d="M11.5 9c0 0.266-0.234 0.5-0.5 0.5s-0.5-0.234-0.5-0.5c0-1.078-1.672-1.5-2.5-1.5-0.266 0-0.5-0.234-0.5-0.5s0.234-0.5 0.5-0.5c1.453 0 3.5 0.766 3.5 2.5zM14 9c0-3.125-3.172-5-6-5s-6 1.875-6 5c0 1 0.406 2.047 1.062 2.812 0.297 0.344 0.641 0.672 0.953 1.031 1.109 1.328 2.047 2.891 2.203 4.656h3.563c0.156-1.766 1.094-3.328 2.203-4.656 0.313-0.359 0.656-0.688 0.953-1.031 0.656-0.766 1.062-1.813 1.062-2.812zM16 9c0 1.609-0.531 3-1.609 4.188s-2.5 2.859-2.625 4.531c0.453 0.266 0.734 0.766 0.734 1.281 0 0.375-0.141 0.734-0.391 1 0.25 0.266 0.391 0.625 0.391 1 0 0.516-0.266 0.984-0.703 1.266 0.125 0.219 0.203 0.484 0.203 0.734 0 1.016-0.797 1.5-1.703 1.5-0.406 0.906-1.313 1.5-2.297 1.5s-1.891-0.594-2.297-1.5c-0.906 0-1.703-0.484-1.703-1.5 0-0.25 0.078-0.516 0.203-0.734-0.438-0.281-0.703-0.75-0.703-1.266 0-0.375 0.141-0.734 0.391-1-0.25-0.266-0.391-0.625-0.391-1 0-0.516 0.281-1.016 0.734-1.281-0.125-1.672-1.547-3.344-2.625-4.531s-1.609-2.578-1.609-4.188c0-4.25 4.047-7 8-7s8 2.75 8 7z"></path>
</svg>
</svg>
 <svg id="css-filter" viewBox="0 0 16 28" height="150" width="150" fill="red">
<path d="M11.5 9c0 0.266-0.234 0.5-0.5 0.5s-0.5-0.234-0.5-0.5c0-1.078-1.672-1.5-2.5-1.5-0.266 0-0.5-0.234-0.5-0.5s0.234-0.5 0.5-0.5c1.453 0 3.5 0.766 3.5 2.5zM14 9c0-3.125-3.172-5-6-5s-6 1.875-6 5c0 1 0.406 2.047 1.062 2.812 0.297 0.344 0.641 0.672 0.953 1.031 1.109 1.328 2.047 2.891 2.203 4.656h3.563c0.156-1.766 1.094-3.328 2.203-4.656 0.313-0.359 0.656-0.688 0.953-1.031 0.656-0.766 1.062-1.813 1.062-2.812zM16 9c0 1.609-0.531 3-1.609 4.188s-2.5 2.859-2.625 4.531c0.453 0.266 0.734 0.766 0.734 1.281 0 0.375-0.141 0.734-0.391 1 0.25 0.266 0.391 0.625 0.391 1 0 0.516-0.266 0.984-0.703 1.266 0.125 0.219 0.203 0.484 0.203 0.734 0 1.016-0.797 1.5-1.703 1.5-0.406 0.906-1.313 1.5-2.297 1.5s-1.891-0.594-2.297-1.5c-0.906 0-1.703-0.484-1.703-1.5 0-0.25 0.078-0.516 0.203-0.734-0.438-0.281-0.703-0.75-0.703-1.266 0-0.375 0.141-0.734 0.391-1-0.25-0.266-0.391-0.625-0.391-1 0-0.516 0.281-1.016 0.734-1.281-0.125-1.672-1.547-3.344-2.625-4.531s-1.609-2.578-1.609-4.188c0-4.25 4.047-7 8-7s8 2.75 8 7z"></path>
</svg>
<hr>
<p>With inline filter</p><p>With css filter</p>
```

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feOffsetElement are just numbers, you cannot provide any units.

Comment: @RobertLongson thank you for the reference. Do you know whether it's possible to redefine the units to match the `px` values assigned in css in a responsive way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two filters should be equivalent and behave the same. Your problem is that you are applying the filters in two different ways.

In the first case, you are applying the filter to the shape **inside** the SVG, so the offsets are being affected by the `viewBox` transform.  Thus they are being scaled larger.

In the second case, you are applying the filter to the final SVG at the document level. So the 1px offsets are being treated as an actual 1px.

To make them behave the same, simply move the filter for the first one to the outermost `<svg>` element, so that it is being applied the same way.

See below.

```css
#css-filter {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 #333);
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 #333);
}

hr {
  clear:both;
}

svg, p {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<svg id="icons-defs" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" filter="url(#filter)">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter" height="130%" width="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="0"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feOffset dx="1" dy="1" result="offsetblur"></feOffset>
      <feFlood flood-color="#333"></feFlood>
      <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"></feComposite>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 16 28" height="150" width="150" fill="yellow">
    <path d="M11.5 9c0 0.266-0.234 0.5-0.5 0.5s-0.5-0.234-0.5-0.5c0-1.078-1.672-1.5-2.5-1.5-0.266 0-0.5-0.234-0.5-0.5s0.234-0.5 0.5-0.5c1.453 0 3.5 0.766 3.5 2.5zM14 9c0-3.125-3.172-5-6-5s-6 1.875-6 5c0 1 0.406 2.047 1.062 2.812 0.297 0.344 0.641 0.672 0.953 1.031 1.109 1.328 2.047 2.891 2.203 4.656h3.563c0.156-1.766 1.094-3.328 2.203-4.656 0.313-0.359 0.656-0.688 0.953-1.031 0.656-0.766 1.062-1.813 1.062-2.812zM16 9c0 1.609-0.531 3-1.609 4.188s-2.5 2.859-2.625 4.531c0.453 0.266 0.734 0.766 0.734 1.281 0 0.375-0.141 0.734-0.391 1 0.25 0.266 0.391 0.625 0.391 1 0 0.516-0.266 0.984-0.703 1.266 0.125 0.219 0.203 0.484 0.203 0.734 0 1.016-0.797 1.5-1.703 1.5-0.406 0.906-1.313 1.5-2.297 1.5s-1.891-0.594-2.297-1.5c-0.906 0-1.703-0.484-1.703-1.5 0-0.25 0.078-0.516 0.203-0.734-0.438-0.281-0.703-0.75-0.703-1.266 0-0.375 0.141-0.734 0.391-1-0.25-0.266-0.391-0.625-0.391-1 0-0.516 0.281-1.016 0.734-1.281-0.125-1.672-1.547-3.344-2.625-4.531s-1.609-2.578-1.609-4.188c0-4.25 4.047-7 8-7s8 2.75 8 7z"></path>
  </svg>
</svg>

<svg id="css-filter" viewBox="0 0 16 28" height="150" width="150" fill="red">
  <path d="M11.5 9c0 0.266-0.234 0.5-0.5 0.5s-0.5-0.234-0.5-0.5c0-1.078-1.672-1.5-2.5-1.5-0.266 0-0.5-0.234-0.5-0.5s0.234-0.5 0.5-0.5c1.453 0 3.5 0.766 3.5 2.5zM14 9c0-3.125-3.172-5-6-5s-6 1.875-6 5c0 1 0.406 2.047 1.062 2.812 0.297 0.344 0.641 0.672 0.953 1.031 1.109 1.328 2.047 2.891 2.203 4.656h3.563c0.156-1.766 1.094-3.328 2.203-4.656 0.313-0.359 0.656-0.688 0.953-1.031 0.656-0.766 1.062-1.813 1.062-2.812zM16 9c0 1.609-0.531 3-1.609 4.188s-2.5 2.859-2.625 4.531c0.453 0.266 0.734 0.766 0.734 1.281 0 0.375-0.141 0.734-0.391 1 0.25 0.266 0.391 0.625 0.391 1 0 0.516-0.266 0.984-0.703 1.266 0.125 0.219 0.203 0.484 0.203 0.734 0 1.016-0.797 1.5-1.703 1.5-0.406 0.906-1.313 1.5-2.297 1.5s-1.891-0.594-2.297-1.5c-0.906 0-1.703-0.484-1.703-1.5 0-0.25 0.078-0.516 0.203-0.734-0.438-0.281-0.703-0.75-0.703-1.266 0-0.375 0.141-0.734 0.391-1-0.25-0.266-0.391-0.625-0.391-1 0-0.516 0.281-1.016 0.734-1.281-0.125-1.672-1.547-3.344-2.625-4.531s-1.609-2.578-1.609-4.188c0-4.25 4.047-7 8-7s8 2.75 8 7z"></path>
</svg>

<hr>
<p>With inline filter</p><p>With css filter</p>
```

Comment: I just started composing an answer myself, and since my conclusions are more or less identical, let me just add here: it would be more appropriate to apply the filter to a enclosing `<span style="filter:url(#filter)">`, not to a `<svg>` which could again have responsiveness issues (if percentage width/height would be used). The overall order of operations is stated in the SVG 2 spec in [How groups are rendered](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/render.html#Grouping), which seems also to apply to inner `<svg>`s.

Comment: Another issue I havn't been able to resolve is this: why do CSS filters do _not_ conform to the processing order?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Paul. How is it then treated in case you are using `<svg><use href="..." /></svg>`? I guess applying filter to the svg in this case, which is actually refeencing Another svg and symbol, will give the same result and be effected by the symbols viewbox?

Comment: If you apply the filter to an outermost `<svg>` element, it shouldn't be affected by the `viewBox` transform.  If you apply the filter to an element inside the SVG it will.