# What is the processing order for filters on a <svg> element in SVG 2.0?

Tags: svg, css-filters

[This recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262474/svg-filter-feoffset-possible-to-set-dx-and-dy-in-pixel-value) touched on how filter and viewBox attributes on a `<svg>` element interact. At first glance, Paul LeBeau's answer seemed to be evident: first the filter is applied, then the implied transformation from the viewBox is applied to the result.

But searching through the spec didn't turn up a clear-cut answer after all, and browser implementations widely vary. I have designed a test case that also examines an additional `transform` attribute on the same element:

```
<svg filter="url(#filter)" width="50" height="50"
     viewBox="0 0 10 10" transform="scale(-1 1)">
```

As it turns out, there is a difference in processing between `<svg>` elements that are outermost, and nested `<svg>` elements - while browsers do not agree what the difference should be:

```
<svg width="50" height="50">
  <svg filter="url(#filter)" width="50" height="50"
       viewBox="0 0 10 10" transform="translate(100) scale(-1 1)">
```

(`transform` attributes are btw new in SVG 2, I included them because their presence made it easier to figure out what the browsers were doing.)

Here is the full test case with inlined SVGs; results for standalone files are identical:

```css
svg {
    overflow:visible;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 100px 60px;
}
td {
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100px;
    height: 75px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
  <filter id="filter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-25" y="0" width="75" height="75">
    <feOffset dx="-5" dy="5" result="bottomright" />
    <feFlood flood-color="red" result="color" />
    <feComposite in="color" in2="bottomright" operator="in" result="shadow" />
    <feFlood flood-color="lightgrey" flood-opacity="0.5" result="bg" />
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode in="bg" />
      <feMergeNode in="shadow" />
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  <filter id="filter2" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-50%" y="0%" width="150%" height="150%">
    <feOffset dx="-5" dy="5" result="bottomright" />
    <feFlood flood-color="red" result="color" />
    <feComposite in="color" in2="bottomright" operator="in" result="shadow" />
    <feFlood flood-color="lightgrey" flood-opacity="0.5" result="bg" />
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode in="bg" />
      <feMergeNode in="shadow" />
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
</svg>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
           style="filter:url(#filter);fill:green"
           viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="50" height="50">
        <rect width="10" height="10" />
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
           style="filter:url(#filter2);fill:green"
           viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="50" height="50">
        <rect width="10" height="10" />
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
           style="filter:url(#filter);fill:green"
           transform="scale(-1 1)" width="10" height="10">
        <rect width="10" height="10" />
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
           style="filter:url(#filter2);fill:green"
           transform="scale(-1 1)" width="10" height="10">
        <rect width="10" height="10" />
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
           style="filter:url(#filter);fill:green"
           viewBox="0 0 10 10" transform="scale(-1 1)" width="50" height="50">
        <rect width="10" height="10" />
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
           style="filter:url(#filter2);fill:green"
           viewBox="0 0 10 10" transform="scale(-1 1)" width="50" height="50">
        <rect width="10" height="10" />
      </svg>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>outer &lt;svg viewBox&gt; userSpaceOnUse</td>
    <td>outer &lt;svg viewBox&gt; objectBoundingBox</td>
    <td>outer &lt;svg transform&gt; userSpaceOnUse</td>
    <td>outer &lt;svg transform&gt; objectBoundingBox</td>
    <td>outer &lt;svg transform viewBox&gt; userSpaceOnUse</td>
    <td>outer &lt;svg transform viewBox&gt; objectBoundingBox</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
        <svg style="filter:url(#filter);fill:green"
             viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="50" height="50">
          <rect width="10" height="10" />
        </svg>
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
        <svg style="filter:url(#filter2);fill:green"
             viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="50" height="50">
          <rect width="10" height="10" />
        </svg>
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
        <svg style="filter:url(#filter);fill:green"
             transform="translate(10) scale(-1 1)" width="10" height="10">
          <rect width="10" height="10" />
        </svg>
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
        <svg style="filter:url(#filter2);fill:green"
             transform="translate(10) scale(-1 1)" width="10" height="10">
          <rect width="10" height="10" />
        </svg>
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
        <svg style="filter:url(#filter);fill:green"
             viewBox="0 0 10 10" transform="translate(100) scale(-1 1)" width="50" height="50">
          <rect width="10" height="10" />
        </svg>
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
        <svg style="filter:url(#filter2);fill:green"
             viewBox="0 0 10 10" transform="translate(100) scale(-1 1)" width="50" height="50">
          <rect width="10" height="10" />
        </svg>
      </svg>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>nested &lt;svg viewBox&gt; userSpaceOnUse</td>
    <td>nested &lt;svg viewBox&gt; objectBoundingBox</td>
    <td>nested &lt;svg transform&gt; userSpaceOnUse</td>
    <td>nested &lt;svg transform&gt; objectBoundingBox</td>
    <td>nested &lt;svg transform viewBox&gt; userSpaceOnUse</td>
    <td>nested &lt;svg transform viewBox&gt; objectBoundingBox</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've been trying to deduce the processing algorithms used by different browsers. I am aware that there is some amount of interpretation involved and it might in fact be implemented diferently, but the basic differences remain and stand out.

The term [initial coordinates](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/coords.html#InitialCoordinateSystem) is the one described as

> For the outermost svg element, the SVG user agent must determine an initial viewport coordinate system and an initial local coordinate system such that the two coordinates systems are identical. The origin of both coordinate systems must be at the origin of the SVG viewport, and one unit in the initial coordinate system must equal one CSS px in the SVG viewport.

The term [viewBox coordinates](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) is the one resulting from applying the transform described as

> The presence of the `viewBox` attribute results in a transformation being applied to the viewport coordinate system as described in [Computing the equivalent transform of an SVG viewport](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/coords.html#ComputingAViewportsTransform).

#### Firefox

for outer `svg` elements

1. transform content to **initial** coordinates
2. determine filter effects region values in **initial** coordinates
3. render `filter` with primitive values in **initial** coordinates
4. clip rendered content to filter effects region in **initial** coordinates
5. apply `transform` attribute to result

for nested `svg` elements

1. determine filter effects region values in **viewBox** coordinates
2. transform content to **initial** coordinates
3. render `filter` with primitive values in **initial** coordinates
4. clip rendered content to filter effects region in **initial** coordinates
5. apply `transform` attribute to result

#### Chrome

for outer `svg` elements

1. transform content to **initial** coordinates
2. determine filter effects region values in **initial** coordinates
3. render `filter` with primitive values in **initial** coordinates
4. clip rendered content to filter effects region in **initial** coordinates
5. apply `transform` attribute to result

for nested `svg` elements

1. determine filter effects region values in **viewBox** coordinates
2. render `filter` with primitive values in **viewBox** coordinates
3. clip rendered content to filter effects region in **viewBox** coordinates
4. transform result to **initial** coordinates
5. ignore `transform` attribute

#### Edge

for outer `svg` elements, filters are not applied.

for nested `svg` elements

1. determine filter effects region values in **viewBox** coordinates
2. render `filter` with primitive values in **viewBox** coordinates
3. clip rendered content to filter effects region in **viewBox** coordinates
4. transform result to **initial** coordinates
5. ignore `transform` attribute

For outer `svg` elements, the browsers (with the exception of Edge, who fails to apply them) agree that the filter is applied to the element after it has been implicitly scaled by the `viewBox`, and the clipping to the filter effects region happens in the same coordinate system. `transform` attributes are applied to the result after filtering.

For nested `svg` elements, Firefox applies the filter to the scaled element, but the clipping to the filter effects region remains unscaled, and clips off most of the scaled content.

Chrome and Edge change the processing order for nested `svg` elements and apply the filter and cliping to the filter effects region in the viewBox coordinate system. The implicit transformation is only then applied, scaling up both content and effects region. `transform` attributes on nested `<svg>` elements are ignored.

#### The SVG 2 draft

There is [one explicit description](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/render.html#Grouping) of processing order:

> Grouping elements, such as the ‘g’ element (see [container elements](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#TermContainerElement)) create a compositing group...
>
> Thus, rendering a compositing group follows the following steps:
>   If the group is isolated:
>
> 1. The initial backdrop is set to a new buffer initialised with rgba(0,0,0,0)
> 2. The contents of the group that are graphics elements or ‘g’ elements are rendered in order, onto the initial backdrop
> 3. filters and other effects that modify the group canvas are applied
>
>    > To provide for high quality rendering, filter primitives and other bitmap effects must be applied in the [operating coordinate space](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#operating-coordinate-space).
> 4. Group transforms are applied
> 5. The group canvas is blended and composited with the group backdrop

While `<svg>` elements are not explicitely mentioned, the linked "container elements" glossary term lists them, and [further down](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/render.html#ParentCompositing) this is said on the subject of compositing:

> In accordance with the Compositing and Blending specification, the `<svg>` element always creates an isolated group.

I've found no explicit mention of processing orders when a transform is the result of a `viewBox`, step 4 *seems* to only have a `transform` attribute in mind. Also, a distinction between outer and nested `<svg>` elements seems not to have been described.

The following [Annotation](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) about ongoing discussions in the draft handles the use of the `transform`:

> Transform on the `<svg>` element is a bit special due to the `viewBox` attribute. The transform should be applied as if the `<svg>` had a parent element with that transform set.
>
> [RESOLUTION](http://www.w3.org/2015/01/08-svg-minutes.html): transform property applies conceptually to the outside of the `<svg>` element and there is no difference between presentation attribute and style property (in terms of the visual result).

#### The Filter Effects Module Level 1 draft

It does only reference SVG 1.1 as an [interacting module](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#placement) and only refers to a "user coordinate system" on the definition of the [filter effects region](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#FilterEffectsRegion):

> If `filterUnits` is equal to `userSpaceOnUse`, `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` represent values in the current user coordinate system in place at the time when the `<filter>` element is referenced (i.e., the user coordinate system for the element referencing the filter element...)
>
> If `filterUnits` is equal to `objectBoundingBox`, `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` represent fractions or percentages of the bounding box on the referencing element...

Concerning [filter primitive units](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#element-attrdef-filter-primitiveunits), it uses the term "local coordinate system", which in the linked glossary from CSS transforms is equivalent to "user coordinate system":

> If `primitiveUnits` is equal to `userSpaceOnUse`, any length values within the filter definitions represent values in the current [local coordinate system](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#local-coordinate-system) in place at the time when the filter element is referenced (i.e., the user coordinate system for the element referencing the `<filter>` element...)
>
> If `primitiveUnits` is equal to `objectBoundingBox`, then any length values within the filter definitions represent fractions or percentages of the bounding box on the referencing element...

All that leaves me with the following questions:

1. Can a clear processing order be determined from the SVG 2 spec? What is that order?
2. Should processing order differ for outer and nested `<svg>` elements? How?

Comment: Transform on an <svg> element is new in SVG 2. Not sure any browser other than Firefox supports it yet really. At any rate isn't this better asked as a [spec clarification question for w3c](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues) rather than here?

Comment: Most of the issues remain even without considering `transform`. I first wanted to find out if I was missing something obvious - and whether maybe some of the browser behaviour could be classified as bug in any case.

Comment: browsers differ as to their interpretation of how viewBox applies to attributes of the element that has the viewBox although they are consistent with how viewBox applies to child elements.

Comment: How does that help? Filters are non-inheritable, i.e. not applied to the child elements, but to the element establishing the viewport.

Comment: I mean I'd expect a filter applied to a child element where the parent is an <svg> with a viewBox to be more consistent than a filter applied to an <svg> with a viewBox directly because of the how does viewBox apply to the element itself problem. Firefox says it doesn't, other browsers say it does.