# add drop-shadow to svg polygon

Tags: css, svg

In the attached snippet, I have a polygon and I need to add an effect to make it look like this:

[image]

I don't know how to do this in svg, if it was html then I think I would use box-shadow.

THe only thing that appears to be a solution is to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) but I think I can only use that on an `<svg/>` element so I am struggling how I can do this.

```css
polygon {
  fill: #5091b9;
  stroke: #4387b0;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300">
  <g transform="translate(100, 100)">
    <polygon points="25.98076211353316,-14.999999999999998 25.98076211353316,14.999999999999998 1.83697019872103e-15,30 -25.98076211353316,14.999999999999998 -25.980762113533157,-15.000000000000004 -5.510910596163089e-15,-30" class="node-vertical__hexagon node-vertical__inactive">         </polygon>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: yes you can use the drop-shadow filter on the SVG and you will have the shadow around the polygon

Comment: I have many of these polygons.  Are you saying I svg elements nested in svg elements?

Comment: well, if you have many element inside the same svg all will get the shadow

Comment: You could save your [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_feoffset.asp) as a separate SVG with the `defs` in it for the filter and apply them via `use xlink:href`

Comment: Just to avoid confusion: SVG filters are for the use on HTML or SVG content elements, see [CSS filter spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/). No `<use>` needed, you reference them with a CSS `url()` function. Using them on a `<svg>` element itself might even have [unexpected issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295274) if combined with a `viewBox`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can apply the `drop-shadow` filter to the SVG OR use the SVG as a background of an element and apply  filter to it:

```css
polygon {
  fill: #5091b9;
  stroke: #4387b0;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
.filter {
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 0 5px red);
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100"><g transform="translate(50, 50)"><polygon stroke="%234387b0" stroke-width="2" fill="%235091b9" points="25.98076211353316,-14.999999999999998 25.98076211353316,14.999999999999998 1.83697019872103e-15,30 -25.98076211353316,14.999999999999998 -25.980762113533157,-15.000000000000004 -5.510910596163089e-15,-30" ></polygon></g></svg>');
}
```

```html
<p>SVG element</p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" class="filter"><g transform="translate(50, 50)" ><polygon points="25.98076211353316,-14.999999999999998 25.98076211353316,14.999999999999998 1.83697019872103e-15,30 -25.98076211353316,14.999999999999998 -25.980762113533157,-15.000000000000004 -5.510910596163089e-15,-30" ></polygon></g></svg>
<p>SVG as background</p>
<div class="box filter"></div>
```

You can also consider the SVG filter:

```css
.node-vertical__inactive {
  filter:url(#shadow);
}

.node-vertical__hexagon {
  fill: #5091b9;
  stroke: #4387b0;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg>
<defs>
    <filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feDropShadow dx="20" dy="3" stdDeviation="5" flood-color="#5091b9" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
<g class="vx-group" transform="translate(0, 0)">
  <g class="vx-group node-vertical__container" transform="translate(100, 100)"><svg class="node-vertical__inactive" x="0" y="0" style="overflow: visible;"><polygon points="25.98076211353316,-14.999999999999998 25.98076211353316,14.999999999999998 1.83697019872103e-15,30 -25.98076211353316,14.999999999999998 -25.980762113533157,-15.000000000000004 -5.510910596163089e-15,-30" class="node-vertical__hexagon"></polygon></svg>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Much better than what I was thinking, +1

Comment: Do you know why the filter is not applied in this http://jsfiddle.net/dagda1/k0eocxfL/40/ fiddle which is accurate to my source, I would need to nest the svgs.  Can filter not apply to nested svgs?

Comment: @dagda1 I think the CSS filter doesn't work with nested svg .. in this case you can consider the SVG filter, see my updates

Comment: @dagda1 it works on Firefox. Some other browsers have limitations on applying CSS filters to SVG content though.

Comment: @RobertLongson any idea how to change the color of the SVG filter ? ... surprisingly I am not able to find how to :/

Comment: flood-color="blue"

Answer (score 6):

You can use `SVG feOffset, feGaussianBlur, feBlend` instead of `feDropShadow.

```html
<svg width="300" height="300">
    <defs>
    <filter id="poly" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="15" dy="15" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="5" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(100, 100)">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"
  style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;" filter="url(#poly)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

This will help you to make shadows with the exact color of your `SVG` shape no matter what it is so you don't have to set a single color for its shadow.
For more information about this technique, you can visit [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_feoffset.asp).

Comment: Well yes but those aren't technically shadows. If you look at a real shadow it doesn't reflect the colour of the thing casting the shadow.

Comment: @RobertLongson Well that's true the shadow of an opaque object is dark but what about a transparent one. Like a red stained glass or something. Anyway, I just suggest an alternative method to create shadows.

Comment: @RobertLongson If you want a black shadow, you have to add a feColorMatrix primitive before the feOffset: <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />

Comment: @Waruyama Sure and then you've implemented a feDropShadow although without the internal optimisations that the browser can do.

Comment: @RobertLongson That is correct, but unlike feDropShadow it works on Internet Explorer and Edge.